# sql server 2008 - t-sql does not recognize column name from the table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I tried testing T-SQL in sql server 2008. I have a table name `tblStaff` and 3 columns `(UserType, UserName, and Password)`. I tried to select UserType from this table by using the following query:

```
SELECT UserType FROM tblStaff;
```

When executing, it produces error of "`Invalid Column name 'UserType'`". I have no idea.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you see when you `SELECT TOP 10 * FROM tblStaff;`?

Comment: According to [this][1], UserType is a SQL keyword.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291293/linqer-wont-do-this-sql

Comment: guy, when I used it with sql server 2005 express, it worked fines, but when I'm upgradding, the problems occurred

Comment: @todda.speot.is I tried and it produces the same error message.

Comment: @Oded: It spends too long to execute this command. I don't know why and what the problem is.

Comment: Select the top 100 rows in SSMS. It will script the select statement for you, with the individual column names correctly escaped.

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner: You can embed links in comments like this: `[text](link)`.

Comment: @Andriy M: Thanks, I'd edit my comment, but that's not possible.

Comment: have you checked for spaces before your columnname ? [ userType]. Try to include the script for creating the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be many reasons for this:

1 - on SQL server management studio make sure you are using that specific database ... the default database your new query will execute on is "master" try this :
USE YOUR_DATABASE_NAME
SELECT UserType FROM tblStaff

2 - make sure you're typing your tablename correctly

3- try using the full path for the table. for example "dbo.tblStaff"

hope this helps

Comment: did you use alias name for your table column ? ... query all the columns and see what happens ? ...

Comment: your simple query takes life time to finish ? and what's the result ? .... are you sure and your SQL service is running in Administration tools\Services ? are you sure you install sql server correctly ?

Answer (score 7):

Edit > Intellisense > Refresh Local Cache